# Regex to find a substring using regex

Tags: regex, grails, groovy

I'm using regex with Groovy(Grails) to find a substring which is a combination of capitalized alphabets, underscores and digits only.

The regex

```
"THIS_WORD" ==~ /([A-Z_0-9]*)/
```

returns `true`
(
but the following statement

```
def str = "Wlkjjf alkjdfas Wk;ljdfs fk THIS_WORD dsklafjf kjd".findAll{([A-Z_0-9]*)/}
println str
```

returns `[W, W, T, H, I, S, _, W, O, R, D]`

I need only the word `THIS_WORD` not alphabet W that is repeated twice. 
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps can you use {2,} instead of * to get all matches with more than 1 char:

```
def str = "Wlkjjf als Wk;lfs fk THIS_WORD dsjf kjd".findAll(/[A-Z_0-9]{2,}/)
```

Comment: Casimir, you mean like `/([A-Z_0-9]{2,})/` ? No that doesn't work either

Comment: @rstarter: are you sure your findall syntaxe is correct? Try with: findall(/[A-Z_09]{2,}/) instead

Comment: Oops...my findAll{} syntax was erroneous...shouldn't have passed it the closure at all...Thanks for pointing that out...accepting the answer!!

Answer (score 1):

- means 0 or more whereas a + means 1 or more. To do 2 or more you would need to use the {MIN,MAX} syntax after the []

> ([A-Z0-9_]{2,})

After learning a bit about groovy and testing on the groovy console at http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/ I found this worked.
​

> def str = "Wlkjjf alkjdfas Wk;ljdfs fk THIS_WORD dsklafjf kjd".findAll(/([A-Z_0-9]{2,})/)
>   println str​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Alex I just did a quick check using groovy console and the result is and empty array []

Comment: Alex your regex is correct...the other syntax of mine was erroneous in fact...Thanks but gonna accept Casimir's answer since he was the first  to answer!!

Answer (score 1):

> def str = "Wlkjjf alkjdfas Wk;ljdfs fk THIS_WORD dsklafjf kjd".findAll{([A-Z_0-9]*)/}

This doesn't compile. Perhaps you meant this:

```
"Wlkjjf alkjdfas Wk;ljdfs fk THIS_WORD dsklafjf kjd".findAll(/[A-Z_0-9]*/)
```

which gives

```
[W, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , W, , , , , , , , , , , , THIS_WORD, , , , , , , , , , , , , , ]
```

If you are looking for all upper-case words, a regex like this will work better:

```
"Wlkjjf alkjdfas Wk;ljdfs fk THIS_WORD dsklafjf kjd".findAll(/\b[A-Z_0-9]+\b/)
```